# Identify connected network printers by its IP address

Tags: c#, printing, dns

I want to list up all printers connected to my network (including not installed)

I could manage to get all IP addresses of connected devices to my PC, by ping to all the addresses on gateway. And then I obtained Host name by

```
IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
return entry.HostName;
```

I noticed that printers does not have a Host name.
 
Now I need to figure out which IP's belongs to a printer of my IP list or mac address.

how can i do that.

When we install a network printer, Windows is listing the names of printers. Can we obtain the such name using IP or MAC?

Answer (score 1):

Include System.Management with

```
using System.Management;

foreach (string printername in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    string query = string.Format("SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}'", printername);

    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
    using (ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get())
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject printer in coll)
            {
                foreach (PropertyData property in printer.Properties)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.Value));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And you will get all the info of every printer, including name and IP

If you want to get the printer IP from the name just use

```
If(printer.Properties.Caption.Contains("Printer name")
{
    return printer.Properties.PortName;
}
```

Otherwise, to obtain the ip from the name, reverse the process and search for the ip and return the name.

For printers in the network, try this:

```
using System.Management;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Management.ObjectQuery oquery = new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
    System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher mosearcher = new
    System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(oquery);
    System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc =
    mosearcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        System.Management.PropertyDataCollection pdc = mo.Properties;
        foreach (System.Management.PropertyData pd in pdc)
        {
            if ((bool)mo["Network"])
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{1}", mo[pd.Name]));
            }
        }
    }
}




// To list printers installed on computer online/offline
Code Snippet
foreach (string printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    MessageBox.Show(printer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. But this gives only installed printers. I need to get all printers. And also I don't know the printer name too.

Comment: What other printers you need to see? It's not clear from the question

Comment: I want to identify all printers connected to my local network

Comment: @mhs Updated the answer. Please mark the answer if solved.

Comment: Appreciate the effort (Up for that). But 'InstalledPrinters' obviously gives installed printers. I need not-installed printers too. this solution can use to get installed network printers.